# Collaborative Sound design via Screen sharing! Which tools do I need?

Tags: workflow

this is a very technical question about workflow optimisation for sound design. I am planing to have a collaboration with a sound designer. We want to be able to work together over a long distance. For the sound design/ foley etc, we used web cams to share our content and connect our sessions. But now we want to mess around with the stuff in our DAWs to see where we can go. We thought about screen sharing with the application Team Viewer. My companion has a PC running cubase, I have a mac using ableton live and protools. Now I can see his DAW, but i can't hear his audio via the program. He is using a tascam Audio interface, and it seems, that he is bypassing the team viewer software.

Is there a tool where I can just send the computer audio from a pc to a mac? Optimal would be a quality of 256k mp3 and higher.

SO the goal would be to work in the same DAW, or at least to be able to see and hear what the other one is doing.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Here are some solutions:

**Virtual Audio Interface**

This would be your best option.

For OSX you have soundflower* for Windows you have Jack Audio* both are free :)

You route the audio from your DAW into the virtual audio interface and than choose the virtual audio interface as an audio input in Team Wiever or Skype.

[image: Soundflower in Ableton Live]

[image: Soundflower in Team Wiever]

**Online DAW:**

If you don't have to use the DAWs you are currently using, you might check out Ohm Studio*

**Project Sync:**

If you have a good internet connection, all of the same plugins and both of you have the same version of both Ableton and Cubase you could sync your project files over for example dropbox.

***Links:**

I was not allowed to post more than two links.

*Soundflower: google "soundflower google code".

*Jack Audio: jackaudio(dot)org/download

*Ohm Studio: ohmstudio(dot)com

Comment: Great, i will have a go with audio jack and sound flower with team viewer.

Comment: Nice :) ... Hint: to also be able to talk to one another, your talking mics have to go trough the DAWs.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used it, but LOLA is supposed to be really amazing:

http://www.conservatorio.trieste.it/artistica/lola-project/lola-low-latency-audio-visual-streaming-system

https://community.ja.net/groups/arts-and-humanities/article/lola-low-latency-audio-visual-streaming-system

I honestly don't know if it does what you need, but interesting none the less.

Comment: Im asking for a licence right now, then i can give a review!